# JBoss deployment throws 'java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file' on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, jboss, zip, ulimit

I deployed a **large EAR** (contained more than ~1024 jars/wars) on **JBoss** running with **Java 6** on **Linux**, and the deployment process cried throwing the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file)
    at org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:53)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.init(MainDeployer.java:901)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.init(MainDeployer.java:895)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:809)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
....
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at org.jboss.util.file.JarArchiveBrowser.<init>(JarArchiveBrowser.java:74)
at org.jboss.util.file.FileProtocolArchiveBrowserFactory.create(FileProtocolArchiveBrowserFactory.java:48)
at org.jboss.util.file.ArchiveBrowser.getBrowser(ArchiveBrowser.java:57)
at org.jboss.ejb3.EJB3Deployer.hasEjbAnnotation(EJB3Deployer.java:213)
....
```

Comment: Answering your own question is fine (even encouraged), but we do ask that you follow the same Question/Answer format as usual.  That is, move the answer part down to a separate Answer.  Thanks, and Welcome!

Comment: Separated the question and the answer as 'Bill the Lizard' suggested. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by the 'limit of number of open file descriptors' in Linux/Unix  operating systems. The default is 1024.

You can check the default value using:

```
ulimit -n
```

To increase the number of open file descriptors (say, to 2048):

```
ulimit -n 2048
```

Check the [man page of ulimit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you can increase the number of open files limit

if you do

```
ulimit -n 2048
```

the value is changed temporarily, it is **reset** after reboot
you better change it by

```
sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf
```

and add these lines by replacing the jboss user name

```
user  soft  nofile 9000
user  hard  nofile 65000
```

after that

```
sudo vi /etc/pam.d/common-session
```

and add

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

restart the server and check the limits

```
ulimit -n
```